# Create git repo using node package.json

Tags: node.js, github, repository, package.json, git-remote

I am just exploring nodejs at the moment and learning about the `package.json` file it creates during as a result of the `npm init` command.

It asks for a git repository and as a result it creates this syntax as part of the file:

```
  "repository" :
   { "type" : "git", 
     "url" : "https://github.com/username/reponame.git"
   }
```

I have tried it with an existing repository and there is no problem, but is there any way to use the package.json to create the remote repository?

I assume you would need to use a token, so it can check your account perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the npm init command [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) doesn't state that possibility, so I doubt that it's directly possible.

But this sounds like an idea for another handy tool.